# Process hangs after executing the second/last command in pipe in certain cases

Tags: c, shell, exec, pipe

I am using pipe, fork & exec to implement a user shell. The issue is that it does not work in certain cases. For eg it would work if I have ls | head but will not work for ls | cat. It will show the output of cat but will simply hang after that without returning to the prompt.

Referring to the code I have the input stored in c->args[0],for which I fork a child & execute it.

I understand that the second exec is still waiting for EOF, but closing file descriptors before that does not help.

Going through similar questions, I also tried closing file descriptors in the parent process before wait but after doing that even ls | head does not work.
I have posted the relevant function below.

```
    void executeProcess(Cmd c,int noofcmds)
{
//    printf("Will be entering fork procedure \n");
     int cmdNo;
     pipe(fd);
  for (cmdNo = 0;cmdNo < noofcmds; cmdNo ++)
  { 

    int processid = fork();
    pid_t childpid;
//    printf("Process id %d\n",processid);
    if (processid == 0)
      { 
//  if (noofcmds != 1)
//       {  
    if (cmdNo == 0)
     {
       printf("Inside first child \n");
       close(fd[0]);
       dup2(fd[1], 1);
//     close(fd[0]); 
     } else if (cmdNo == noofcmds-1)
     {  
       close(fd[1]);
       dup2(fd[0], 0);
//         close(fd[0]);

     }
//  close(fd[1]);
//  close(fd[0]);
        if (execvp(c->args[0],c->args) < 1)
     { printf("Error\n");
     }
      } else 
      {
//  printf("Waiting in parent\n");
//  close(fd[0]);
//  close(fd[1]);

    int status;
    int returnedpid;
    wait(&status);
        printf("Returned after waiting\n");
//  close(fd[0]);
//  close(fd[1]);   
      }
    c = c->next;
//  close(fd[0]);
//  close(fd[1]);
  } // end of for
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the sequence of events, with `ls | cat` this is what happens right now:

1) pipe is created in parent.
2) `ls` child is spawned
3) parent waits for `ls` to finish
4) `cat` child is spawned
5) parent waits for `cat` to finish

As you noticed, in 5) parent still has the pipe open so `cat` never finishes.

When you close it in the parent part of the code it gets closed ... before 3). So by the time `cat` starts the pipe doesn't exist anymore -> no output from `cat`.

What you need is to close it after 4) with something like:

```
...
else  // in parent
{
    // printf("Waiting in parent\n");

    if (cmdNo == 1)  // second child is spawned, can close the pipe now.
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }

    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("Returned after waiting\n");
}
```

Code will need more work to handle more than 2 commands in a pipe, but you get the idea...

Tip: find an editor which indents your code automatically, it'll make your life a lot easier !

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked as a charm !!! Yeah, I first wanted to make sure it works for 2 commands, I will now try the rest of the part.

Comment: Thank god for you. I have scoured the internet looking for this answer. You saved me!